# Adding list of images into a scroll view

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-image

I want to have a scroll bar in android showing each individual plant such that a user can press on one to select it, create a new `Plant` object he can then move around the screen.

I'm running into trouble populating this list.

I have a `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
bar = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
```

The brunt of my code happens in

```
private LinearLayout loadBar(ArrayList<Plant> listOfPlants, HorizontalScrollView bar){
     LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

     layout.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
     ImageView image= new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
     ArrayList<View> images = new ArrayList<View>();
     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

         image = listOfPlants.get(i).getPhoto();
         images.add(image);

    }
    layout.addTouchables(images);
    return layout;
 }
```

I want to add this linear layout to the scroll bar I'm creating but I don't see any way to do this. Or am I going about this the wrong way and is there a much simpler way to get what I want done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a ListView inside LinearLayout, that is inside horizontal scroll view as below:

```
<HorizontalScrollView ...........>
<LinearLayout ......>
    <LinearLayout ......>
    //List View Titles will be here
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView ........ android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Also, it is important to put layout_weight in the ListView. Hope it works for you. Also, you can check this [customized horizontally scrollable listview](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) tutorial.

Comment: I think that tutorial is exactly what I needed! Thanks!